# how to create a dynamic table with colspan if previous entry is the same in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to create a table for a wordpress site.  I would like the table to span the column if entries are the same.  As an example, if I had 4 entries for voltage in my while statement and they were 12, 13, 14, 15 then there would be 4 columns in the voltage row.  If the entries were 12, 12, 12, 12 then there would be one column with a colspan of 4.  If the rows were 12, 12, 24, 24, there would be 2 columns, each with a colspan of 2.  If it were 12, 24, 12, 24, then there would be 4 columns each with colspan 4.

I thought I had this figured out but I'm just doing too many checks I think and can't wrap my head around simplifying this.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
if( have_rows('product_variations') ):

    //if these later come true it prints the colum with a heading
    $pname = '';
    $pnumber ='';
    $pcolor ='';
    $pvoltage ='';
    $pcurrent = '';
    $ppower = '';
    $pwigwag ='';
    $psync = '';
    $plumens = '';
    $pcandela = '';
    $pbeamprofile = '';
    $plength = '';
    $pwidth = '';
    $pdepth = '';
    $pheight = '';
    $pbeamprofile = '';

    //trial for comparing depth
    $comparedepth = '';
    $depthcount = '1';
    //trial for comparing votage
    $comparevoltage = '';
    $voltagecount = '1';
    $testvoltage = '';

    $testcolor = '';
    $testwig = '';

    $count = count(get_field('product_variations'));

    while( have_rows('product_variations') ) : the_row();
        $pname .= '<th>'.get_sub_field('name').'</th>';
        $pnumber .='<td>'.get_sub_field('part_number').'</td>';
        $pcolor .='<td class="'.get_sub_field('color').'">'.get_sub_field('color').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('color')) $testcolor = true;
        if ( get_sub_field('voltage') && $comparevoltage == get_sub_field('voltage') ) {
            $voltagecount++;
            $testvoltage = true;
            $pvoltage .='<td align="center" colspan="'.$voltagecount.'">'.get_sub_field('voltage').'</td>';
            $comparevoltage = get_sub_field('voltage');
        } elseif ( get_sub_field('voltage') ) {
            $testvoltage = true;
            $voltagecount = '1';
            $pvoltage .='<td align="center" colspan="'.$voltagecount.'">'.get_sub_field('voltage').'</td>';
            $comparevoltage = get_sub_field('voltage');
        }
        $pcurrent .='<td>'.get_sub_field('current').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('current')) $testcurrent = true;
        $ppower .='<td>'.get_sub_field('wattage').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('wattage')) $testpower = true;
     if (get_sub_field('wigwag')) {
            $pwigwag .='<td>Yes</td>';
            $testwig = true; 
        } else {
            $pwigwag .='<td>No</td>';
        }
     if (get_sub_field('syncronization')) {
            $psync .='<td>Yes</td>';
            $testsync = true; 
        } else {
            $psync .='<td>No</td>';
        }
        $plumens .='<td>'.get_sub_field('lumens').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('lumens')) $testlumens = true;
        $pcandela .='<td>'.get_sub_field('candella').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('candella')) $testcandela = true;
        $pbeamprofile .='<td>'.get_sub_field('beam_profile').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('beam_profile')) $testbeamprofile = true;
        $plength .='<td>'.get_sub_field('length').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('length')) $testlength = true;
        $pwidth .='<td>'.get_sub_field('width').'</td>';
     if (get_sub_field('width')) $testwidth = true;

        if ( get_sub_field('depth') && $comparedepth == get_sub_field('depth') ) {
            $depthcount++;
            $testdepth = true;
            $pdepth ='<td align="center" colspan="'.$depthcount.'">'.get_sub_field('depth').'</td>';
            $comparedepth = get_sub_field('depth');
        } elseif ( get_sub_field('depth') ) {
            $testdepth = true;
            $pdepth .='<td align="center" colspan="'.$depthcount.'">'.get_sub_field('depth').'</td>';
            $comparedepth = get_sub_field('depth');
        }
        $pweight .='<td>'.get_sub_field('weight').'</td>';
     if ( get_sub_field('weight') ) {
            $testweight = true;
        }
    endwhile;

    $output .= '<tr><th></th>'.$pname.'</tr>';
    $output .= '<tr><th>Part Number</th>'.$pnumber.'</tr>';
    if( $testcolor ) $output .= '<tr><th>Color</th>'.$pcolor.'</tr>';
    if( $testvoltage )$output .= '<tr><th>Voltage</th>'.$pvoltage.'</tr>';
    //if( $testcurrent ) $output .= '<tr><th>Current</th>'.$pcurrent.'</tr>';
    if( $testpower ) $output .= '<tr><th>Power</th>'.$ppower.'</tr>';
    if( $testwig ) $output .= '<tr><th>Wigwag</th>'.$pwigwag.'</tr>';
    if( $testsync ) $output .= '<tr><th>Synchronization</th>'.$psync.'</tr>';
    if( $testlumens ) $output .= '<tr><th>Lumens</th>'.$plumens.'</tr>';
    if( $testcandela ) $output .= '<tr><th>Candela</th>'.$pcandela.'</tr>';
    if( $testbeamprofile ) $output .= '<tr><th>Beam Profile</th>'.$pbeamprofile.'</tr>';
    if( $testlength ) $output .= '<tr><th>Length</th>'.$plength.'</tr>';
    if( $testwidth ) $output .= '<tr><th>Width</th>'.$pwidth.'</tr>';
    if( $testdepth ) $output .= '<tr><th>Depth</th>'.$pdepth.'</tr>';
    if( $testweight ) $output .= '<tr><th>Weight</th>'.$pweight.'</tr>';

endif;
```

Voltage is the one I'm having issues with right now.  Entries are 12, 12, 24, 24.  So I would hope to have html for this row output as :

```
<tr>
<th>Voltage</th>
<td colspan="2" align="center">12</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">24</td>
</tr>
```

However it is actually coming out like this:

```
<tr>
<th>Voltage</th>
<td colspan="1" align="center">12</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">12</td>
<td colspan="1" align="center">24</td>
<td colspan="2" align="center">24</td>
</tr>
```

I know it's because I am not overwriting my `$pvoltage` variable when `if ( get_sub_field('voltage') && $comparevoltage == get_sub_field('voltage') )` is true but I don't know how to add a condition that says when this is the 2nd time around and there have already been some the same.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to track the `$voltagecount` separately for each occurrence of something, you can use associative array to iterate the counter separately.

So instead of one plain variable `$voltagecount` use an associative array where each key will be combination of variables or values you need to be separately counted. So the structure of the array may looks like:

```
// just an example to get an idea about the array structure
$voltagecount['voltage_12'] = 2;
$voltagecount['voltage_24'] = 1;
$voltagecount['depth_12'] = 1;
$voltagecount['depth_24'] = 2;
```

This way you will be able to calculate each counters separately.

Here is the idea of actual coding:

```
 <?php
 // instead of declaring variable as string (why string, you use it as integer anyway???)
 $voltagecount = '1';
 
 // declare it as array
 $voltagecount = array();
 
 // later on in your conditional part initiate the array key with default value 1 just increase by one...
 if( !isset($voltagecount['voltage_'.get_sub_field('voltage')] ){
      $voltagecount['voltage_'.get_sub_field('voltage')] = 1;
 }
 
 // later on when counter needed increase that by one 
 $voltagecount['voltage_'.get_sub_field('voltage')]++;
 
 // printing the colspan value
 $pvoltage .='<td align="center" colspan="'. $voltagecount['voltage_'.get_sub_field('voltage')] .'">'.get_sub_field('voltage').'</td>';
 
 // and finally resetting the counter to init value 
 $voltagecount['voltage_'.get_sub_field('voltage')] = 1;
```

Note since your script is quite complex without live demo I am providing just and ideas. Do adopt the idea to your needs, especially the array keys and placement to fulfill the logic of your script.

Comment: This is actually really helpful, but I think I didn't explain my self well.  thank you for trying